# How to convert base64_encode png image into simple image

Tags: php

Please any suggest to convert base_encode image in to simple image .

Comment: i have base64 encoded image but now i convert back in to as simple png format any help

Comment: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `base64_decode` function.

First decode it and create a file name,

```
$data = base64_decode(explode(",", $base64)[1]); // Cutting off the data we don't need.
$file = '/somefolder/'.uniqid().'.png'; // Generating a unique id so images wont override each other.
```

Then save it to the filesystem.

```
file_put_contents($file, $data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use base64_decode to decode your data.

```
header('Content-type: image/png');
$base64 = 'data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';
$data = explode(',', $base64);
$encodedImage = $data[1];
$decodedImage = base64_decode($encodedImage);
echo $decodedImage;
```